# Why Backslash character not removed even after using replace method

Tags: java, replace, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have made a rest request which is returning me a Set in JSON format which is  **"[\"TestBack\"]"**.

If I directly parse it in Apex using

```
Set<String> rw = (Set<String>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),Set<String>.class);
```

then I get following error

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set
```

but if I explicitly remove double quote sign by using

```
 Set<String> rw = (Set<String>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody().substringAfter('"').substringBeforeLast('"'),Set<String>.class);
```

I got following error

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): expected a valid value
```

and if I try to use replaceAll method

```
Set<String> rw = (Set<String>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody().substringAfter('"').substringBeforeLast('"').replaceAll('\\',''),Set<String>.class);
```

it shows following error

```
FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid regex: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

Is there any way to get parse back into Set?

Comment: Your JSON contains a single string value. That String value appears to be a list in JSON format itself. So either you need to double parse the JSON (once as a string and then the result as a list) or fix the source of the JSON so it only passes the list.

Comment: Btw the reason it failed is that the search re needs double escapement, i.e. `"\\\\"`